# Creating a file system in a file

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems

I need to create a file system in a file in c.  I have been looking for info and example but am having a hard time finding any good resources.  I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this.  I though creating a fat file system would be simplest, but not sure.

Comment: is this homework? If so, please tag as such.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need. "in c" suggests that this is an assignment, otherwise it's a mistake to include such a  specification.

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't know why you are doing this and if this is cheating but here's [one way](http://freshmeat.net/articles/virtual-filesystem-building-a-linux-filesystem-from-an-ordinary-file) to do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a 1 gig empty file
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/where/you/want/fs bs=1M count=1024
# make a filesystem, replace ext3 with desired fstype
mkfs.ext3 /tmp/where/you/want/fs
```

Comment: The OP said "in c (sic)" so this doesn't answer the question (which is somewhat poorly asked).

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that part. I'll this answer up as it's more or less the steps needed anyway, though I agree it's not quite right.

Comment: I think the OP wants to implement a fs on top of a file, not just format a file as a fs. But maybe we'll find out for sure when the OP asks a clearer question.

Comment: @Jim Balter - Neither of our answers addresses the C portion but in fairness it is hard to determine what a new user with no history and a broad question is really seeking.  There are no shortage of questions like "I would like to develop an OS to compete with Windows over spring break, how do I do that?"  It's possible OP really wants to do this from scratch, in which case he can be directed to various theoretical and code sources, or maybe this is just a small part of a larger project that he could just as easily make do with the supplied answers.  He should clarify his objective.

Comment: @Duck "He should clarify his objective" -- Um, see my comment under the OP's question, posted long before you telling me that.

Comment: @Jim Balter -  I know.  I was agreeing with you.